# Bootstrap 5 : Footer full width not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am currently using the Bootstrap footer example and I am having a hard time figuring out how to make the footer in full width.

[image: bootstrap footer screenshot]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">

  <footer class="py-4 bg-dark">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="text-center text-muted">&copy; 2022 Company, Inc</p>
  </footer>

</div>
```

I already tried to add `footer {width: 100%;}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap container classes add padding to the left and right. according to doc you can add `px-0` along with container classes.

```html
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
....
</div>
```